# How to ping from a tuple?

Tags: python

How can I ping a list of hosts from a tuple and store the response into another tuple, list?

I know how to ping a single host:

```
hostname = "10.0.0.250" #example

response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
```

Comment: You need to attempt to solve the problem yourself before asking a question. Show us a complete, working example that illustrates where you're getting stuck. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a *list comprehension* / *generator expression* (for tuple), given a tuple of hostnames:

```
hostnames = ("10.0.0.250", "10.0.0.240", ...)
responses = tuple(os.system("ping -c 1 " + h) for h in hostnames)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hostnames = ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]
# Can use a tuple instead of list.
responses = [os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname) for hostname in hostnames]
# You can enwrap the list comprehension in a call to the tuple() function
# to make `responses` a tuple instead of list.
```